# Populate a Django form field with choices from database (but not from a model)

Tags: django, django-forms

I'd like to populate a form dropdown with data from database.
Those data don't come directly from a model but from a raw query.

This is working when the database is available and the migrations are already generated. Otherwise, generating the migrations (`python manage.py makemigrations myapp`) fails because Django evaluates `_all_departments()` which is not able to find the appropriate table.

```py
def _all_departments() -> List[Tuple[str, str]]:
    from django.db import connection
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("select distinct department from crm_mytable order by department")
        return [(row[0], row[0]) for row in cursor.fetchall()]


class MyForm(forms.Form):
    department = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.SelectMultiple(choices=_all_departments()))
```

I naively tried to update manually the choices on `__init__` without success (choices are always empty):

```py
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['department'].widget.choices = _all_departments()

    department = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.SelectMultiple(choices=[]))
```

What would be the way to properly fill on-demand the choices?

Comment: Your first solution doesn't work because you're probably importing the `MyForm` somewhere in your views (which are imported when django is started during any manage.py operation) and therefore the function `_all_departments` gets evaluated. Your second solution should work.

Comment: As a matter of interest, why don't you define a model to represent your department table?

Comment: I have no good reason for not doing it. In a real application, I would probably do it, by the way. The application I'm working on is more like a toy to discover and evaluate Django features.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should *not* pass the `choices` to the *widget*, but to the *field*. You furthermore probably want to use a [**`MultipleChoiceField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield), this uses a [**`SelectMultiple`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.SelectMultiple) as default widget:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):

    department = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=[])

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['department'].choices = _all_departments()
```

Comment: Agreed that a MultipleChoiceField is a better path, but why wouldn't setting the choices on the widget work? A `ChoiceWidget` (which is parent of `SelectMultiple`) has `choices` in its initialiser which sets its property `choices` so why wouldn't that work?

Comment: @dirkgroten: because the *field* validates if the choices are *valid*, in fact the widget only "talks" to the field and specifies how to *render* the choices. Widget's only specify how to *render* something, not how to *retrieve* something, validate something, etc.

Comment: But he's using a CharField, which doesn't validate the choices and forces the list received by the widget to be forced into a text. I would at least expect the widget to render with the choices and the Charfield to return the list as a string.

Comment: @dirkgoten: when you construct the `Field` (notice that this happens *after* you constructed the widget), it sets its choices to the choices of the widget: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_modules/django/forms/fields/#ChoiceField

Comment: The field is constructed in the super().__init__() isn't it? So widget choices are overriden after the field is constructed.

Comment: @dirkgroten: the `widget` you mean? Yes, through `widget = widget()`.

Comment: Doesn't make sense: A form CharField doesn't have choices. When the super().__init__() method is called, both the fields and widgets are constructed. Initially with empty choices for the widget. But in his method, he explicitly sets the choices *after* calling super().__init__(). So the widget should have the correct choices and that's what is used when rendering it.

Comment: In fact I just tested. Initialise a form with a CharField and a Select widget, set the choices of the `widget` for that field and render the field: it renders the new choices.

Comment: @dirkgroten: hmmm... interesting. But I guess there are some problems than with validating it (as in one can make a POST request with options that were non-existing).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sure, a CharField isn't ideal to receive multiple choices and this answer is the correct way to do it. I was just wondering why OP said "choices are always empty", suggesting he didn't see any choices in his HTML form.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, Django 4 accept a *callable* as the value of `choices` (see [reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ChoiceField.choices)).
In your code, move the argument `choices` to the field and skip the `()` after `_all_departments`.

```py
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    department = forms.CharField(choices=_all_departments,
                                 widget=forms.SelectMultiple)
```